# MYSQL select category that contains at least two elements from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Ecommerce: say I have two tables, one Categories, another Items.

```
Categories
-------
category_id
category_name

Items
-----
item_id
item_name
category_id
```

I need to select & list on my page all those Categories that contains at least **two** items.

I also need to know how many Categories overall i have, so i can paginate...
Also, I need to show the number of items under each category if possible with mysql.

so i tried

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
(SELECT * FROM items i WHERE i.category_id = c.category_id) as tot
FROM categories c
RIGHT JOIN items i ON i.category_id = c.category_id
HAVING tot > 1
LIMIT 10
```

but doesn't work... any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a simple aggregation where you group by category and count items.

```
select 
  c.category_id,
  c.category_name,
  count(*) as items
from categories c
join items i on i.category_id = c.category_id
group by c.category_id
having count(*) >= 2
order by c.category_id
limit @skip, @show;
```

If you want to know how many categories match your condition:

```
select count(*)
from categories c
where 
(
  select count(*)
  from items i 
  where i.category_id = c.category_id
) >= 2;
```